# select from two tables and count and order by count total?

Tags: mysql

table A structure id a1 a2
table B structure id time b1 b2

table A data

```
1 .. ..  
2 .. ..  
3 .. ..
```

table B data

```
1 129873635 blah blah  
2 129880006 blah blah  
2 129890676 blah blah  
3 129973635 blah blah  
2 129973635 blah blah  
3 129936350 blah blah  
2 129973635 blah blah  
1 129873835 blah blah
```

I want to select from tablea and also tableb where tablea.id=tableb.id and count tableb where time > x order by count of tableb..

I want results like

```
2 blah blah (which has 4 row in table B)  
1 blah blah (which has 2 row in table B)  
3 blah blah (which has 2 row in table B)
```

Please post the query thanks...

Answer (score 0):

OK First of, id's are supposed to be unique.
I would suggest restructuring tableB as follows:

id, tableA_id, time, b1, b2, ...
That way it is clear that tableA_id points to another table and is not the id of TableB.

```
SELECT count(tableb.*), tablea.a1, tableB.time 
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON (tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id)
WHERE tableB.time > now()
GROUP BY tablea.id
ORDER BY count(tableB.*)
```

For speed index the fields
TableA.id (primary key)
TableB.id (primary key)
TableB.TableA_id
TableB.Time
TableB.blah (just for luck)

Comment: SELECT count(b_userchatmem.*),b_userchatmem.time 
FROM b_rooms
INNER JOIN b_userchatmem ON (b_userchatmem.roomid = b_rooms.roomid)
WHERE b_userchatmem.time > now()
GROUP BY b_rooms.roomid
ORDER BY count(b_userchatmem.*)


i am getting error plz see this